# Excel 2010 check cells in a row contain data before the Selection Change fires

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have an Excel 2010 data table which is driven by a query from MSSQL.  The underlying query changes depending upon what options the user selects in the Excel workbook.  I'm okay with changing the query and pulling the data.

After the data has been selected multiple users will be able to edit and append data to the Excel table and these changes will post back to the SQL database table.  Due to the database table structure some of these cells within a given row are mandatory before any data can be inserted into MSSQL and/or potentially updated.

So what I'm trying to achieve is checks on whether certain columns in a row are blank after a cell is edited (I can do this via Worksheet Change) and also before they move off that row so I can bring up a message if all mandatory columns haven't been entered.  I can't see any events that fire before Selection Change.  My only thoughts on a workaround is to have a global variable row marker that is updated on Selection Change, i.e. it will store the previous row number.  I can't use Excel's standard data validation functionality looking at blank cells because although this is fine for a currently correctly populated row that is being edited, inserting new rows or appending directly to the bottom of the table will constantly error as all those mandatory columns will, of course, be blank.  Currently I am using conditional formatting to at least highlight columns/cells that require input although this doesn't force users to actually do it.  Data cannot be stored within MSSQL until these columns contain data so if they don't fill them in and refresh the table for whatever reason, whatever they have entered will be lost.  Obviously this is bad, m'kay.  I am concerned about both the Worksheet Change and Selection Change events constantly firing and how that will affect workbook performance.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Maybe I'm going about this all wrong so any ideas to make this more efficient would also be well received.  The user base do not want to see UserForms or MS Access even though it would make this activity very easy.  They are too used to the look and feel of Excel sheets.

Comment: You have to be *very* careful letting people work on data in Excel and then upload/update it back to a database.  One bad sort or mistaken "fill-down" and your data is hosed.  One approach is to lock the worksheet after querying the data, and only unlock one row at a time after the user clicks an "edit" button or something like that.  Another is to keep a copy of the original queried data on a hidden sheet, so that you will have some way to determine what/how many updates were made before re-uploading edited data or adding new rows.

Comment: @TimWilliams I am already using a hidden sheet with a copy of the original query so that I can keep an audit log of cell edits and newly appended rows.  Any idea about the validation aspect for new rows?

Comment: maybe this can help a bit https://sites.google.com/site/beyondexcel/project-updates/createdatabaseswithexcel and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9cUYpXIKsU

Comment: I would not try to validate data as the user enters it, but instead when they trigger an update back to the database.  It can be a bit annoying to have messageboxes popping up if you're not finished working on your data entry...   If you want to have "live" indications of problems then I would use Data Validation (even though it's tricky to deal with new rows).  If each record has a unique "Id" then including that in the dataset helps you determine which rows are being edited vs. which rows are added by the user.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not showing messages after each cell is entered in a given row because as you say this will be annoying.  Conditional formatting is being used to highlight cells that are mandatory.  The important bit is if the user moves off that row suggesting they have finished entering.  That's when I'd like to have something that ensures they go back to complete at least the minimum of data input.  Can I undo/cancel a Selection Change if it is not on the same row?  I suppose a global variable always storing the last row visited would solve this.  I am already using an ID as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

your best way is to copy the table into 2d array or some other data structure in memory such as dictionary or collection. and than manage each change in memory. this one is very efficient but requires a lot of code. with excel the only problem you have is the key the rest is vlookup and true false questions. vlookup will find the original value and then you have current data + previous data + the logic...  is the new data ok?

Comment: I'm already using a data table and I  don't have a problem with comparing cell values before and after editing.  I'm more concerned about how to validate that 7 columns in a given row contain data particularly before the user moves off that row. Also I don't know if checking these columns within every worksheet or selection change will kill the performance.

Comment: if(and(b1<>"",..., b10<>""), true, false) ... i would change the true to red flag char (weddings) and the false to "". add submit button.  and do all work on one go